How to set flatclasspath in QuarkusTest
I have problems with classloading in QuarkusTests which could be solved if I could set the existing boolean property flatclasspath in QuarkusBootstrap.Builder.
I tested this by setting it during debugging.
Sadly, I did not find a way to set this by configuration, Environment, Define, ...
Does anybody know a way to solve this, did I overlook anything or is it just dead code.
The Quarkus-Version I am using is 3.2.10, I also tested using 3.12.0
